# Facebook comment plugin does not show up on Chrome or IE 9

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have a problem. I created an HTML page and inserted the below script (to get Facebook Comment Plugin) and the `div` tag showed up on a random scrap page I created, but again disappeared. However, I'm still not able to figure out why it doesn't work on the page I want it to. Can anybody please help me here?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); 
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=429158573799321";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```